# Build on PR, but only push image on merge or release

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub project which I want to build with Docker and push to the GHCR, via an Action.

I want it to be built whenever there is a pull request, in order to verify that the build works. However, I only want an image to be pushed to the GHCR when the Action is triggered by a push to the `main` branch or a tagged release.

Here's my `build-and-push.yml`:

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
    tags: ['v*']
  pull_request:
    branches: ['main']

env:
  # ...
  DO_PUSH: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' || github.event_name == 'release' }}

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    # ...
    
    steps:
      - 
        name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - 
        name: Log in to GHCR
        if: env.DO_PUSH == true
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        # ...
      - 
        name: Get Docker metadata
        if: env.DO_PUSH == true
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        # ...
      - 
        name: Only build
        if: env.DO_PUSH != true
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          push: false
      - 
        name: Build and push
        if: env.DO_PUSH == true
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          # ...
```

So, it's a pretty standard build-and-push workflow, with one key difference. `env.DO_PUSH` is defined to be `github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' || github.event_name == 'release'`, which should be `true` if either the Action is triggered by the `main` branch or a release, and `false` if it's triggered by a PR.

Some basic debugging by adding `run: echo ${{ env.DO_PUSH }}` steps confirms that this value is set to what I want it to be. However, the steps marked with the conditional `if: env.DO_PUSH == true` never run, and the 'Only build' step marked with `if: env.DO_PUSH != true` always runs.

For instance, from a push to `main`:

[image]